# mysql упорядочить по возрастанию

Tags: php, mysql

есть база данных с таблицей `user`, в ней в столбце `rsite` отображается информация с какого сайта пришел пользователей. пытаюсь сделать вывод количества сайтов с которого пришел пользователь, получилось:

```
$dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Не подключаюсь.");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT rsite, COUNT(rsite) AS cnt FROM user GROUP BY rsite asc");
echo "<caption>Количество регистраций с сайтов:</caption>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo "<table><tr><td>".$row['rsite']." - ".$row['cnt']."</td></tr></table>"; 
}
```

здесь выводится название сайта и через тире количество в таблице с упорядочивание по алфавиту "rsite asc", т.е.

- asite - 3
- bsite - 1
- csite - 10

а как сделать чтобы упорядочивало по количеству, т.е.

- bsite - 1
- asite - 3
- csite - 10

спасибо за ответ

Comment: добавить в запрос `order by COUNT(rsite)`

Comment: если добавлю так: $query=mysql_query("SELECT rsite, order by COUNT(rsite) AS cnt FROM user GROUP BY rsite asc"); , то ничего не выводится, пусто

Comment: прочитайте базовые сведения по языку sql. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORDER_BY_(SQL) `order by` пишется в конце запроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `rsite`, COUNT(`rsite`) AS `cnt`
FROM `user`
GROUP BY `rsite` ASC
ORDER BY `cnt` ASC
```

Comment: спасибо, все получилось